# Имена модификаторов в CSS по методологии БЭМ

Tags: css, бэм

На официальном сайте ru.bem.info в разделе FAQ заинтересовали два вопроса.
Первый:

> **Как выбрать имя модификатора?**
>
> Выбирайте имена модификаторов, опираясь на семантику, а не на
>   описываемые им CSS-свойства.
>
> Пример
>
> ```
> <!-- Неудачное имя модификатора -->
> <button class="button button_background_yellow">...</button>
> <!-- Удачное имя модификатора -->
> <button class="button button_view_action">...</button>
> ```
>
> Имя модификатора button_background_yellow неудачное, потому что:
>
> При изменении фона с желтого (yellow), например, на красный (red)
>   придется менять не только CSS-код, но и название селектора, шаблоны и,
>   вполне вероятно, JavaScript-код.
>
> При добавлении других CSS-свойств, например, border, line-height, имя
>   модификатора перестанет соответствовать его содержанию.

Второй:

> **Почему нельзя писать имя модификатора блока в имени элемента
>   (block_mod__elem)?**
>
> Элемент — составная часть блока, а не модификатора блока. Таким
>   образом, только имя блока может задавать пространство имен для
>   элементов.
>
> Это важно, потому что:
>
> Блок может иметь много модификаторов.
>   Пример
>
> ```
> <div class="button button_size_m button_theme_islands button_type_submit">
> <div class="button__text">...</div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> Модификатор определяет состояние блока/элемента, которое может быть изменено во время выполнения скрипта JavaScript.

Разве эти два вопроса не противоречат друг другу? В первом случае говорится, что нельзя называть модификатор **button_background_yellow**, но во втором случае они называют модификатор **button_theme_islands**. Ведь во втором случае, по аналогии с первым, при изменении темы придется менять название и код.

Comment: Нет. Во втором случае если дизайнер решит, что фон островов должен быть синий, а не жёлтый достаточно будет поменять стили, не трогая html. В пером случае тоже можно, но у вас сломается мозг когда вы узнаете, что в классе `.button_background_yellow` написано `backgound-color: blue`

Comment: В общем идея в том, что модификатор должен задавать смысл, а не реализацию.

Comment: А разве мозг не сломается, если в классе .button_theme_islands будет тема не островов, а ,допустим, машины? Ведь по сути и то и то идентично всего одному inline-стилю.